# Photoshop: shift+resize (transform) disables snap to grid function?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grids, snapping

When I grab any side of an object in transform mode, I can have them snap to a grid (purple line is visible to indicate alignment) but whenever I grab a corner to keep the correct ratio, the shift+resize disables snap to grid function. Any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

My workaround is to let it snap unproportionally and than change the skewed width manually by dialing in the value to the percentage of the one side that fits my needs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the behaviour is just as you describe: you can snap if you resize by dragging the side handles but not the corner handles. With aspect ratio now being locked by default you can choose whether to snap with or without the locking the aspect ratio (holding shift key) by choosing which handles you drag. It's weird, don't know if I like it, but it works. Took me weeks to figure it out.